# Service not registered: org.OpenUDID.OpenUDID_manager@2b038438

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an application published in Google play and some time ago i received two error reports in my developer console which looks just like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: org.OpenUDID.OpenUDID_manager@2b038438
at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:891)
at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:921)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:352)
at org.OpenUDID.OpenUDID_manager.onServiceConnected(OpenUDID_manager.java:68)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1064)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1081)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and second:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: org.OpenUDID.OpenUDID_manager@40590d88
at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:934)
at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:952)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:352)
at org.OpenUDID.OpenUDID_manager.onServiceConnected(OpenUDID_manager.java:68)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1107)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1124)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4293)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can somebody explain me what is all this about? Non of the specified packages in stack trace are from my app.

Some of the libraries which i use are adcolony and appbooster. (I suppose that this libs might be the cause of problem).

Answer (score 0):

Have a great new year 2014.if the answer is feasible than raise the answer and points :)

Hi i think i got the this problem please have a look.

Make sur you are using correct context.

one of these days

```
mService.unbindService(mConnection);
```

is obviously nonsense, calling unbind in the wrong context. It should be

```
unbindService(mConnection);
```

Additional mistake in the posted coding is the missing of

```
 @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        // All clients have unbound with unbindService()



        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that this is a solution because i do not bind to any service from my app. At list i didn't write the code to do this. The binding might be proceeded in some of the libs which i use, but they are all jar files. I have no idea how to open them.            PS: However thanks for the answer. And i wish you a happy new year too.